# How to add async attribute to script generated by react scripts (at the npm run build stage on the create-react-app template)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I want to defer parsing of scripts that are generate as a result of transpiling during build. I have added async to all the other tags on my index.html page. However, since the main js file is inject into page during build, it becomes harder.

Is there a way to tell babel/react-scripts to add the async attribute to the injected js tag?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue recently as well when starting out with create-react-app. However, my problem was in the context of pre-rendering the pages statically. I am using [react-snap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap) which has the following configuration option:

```
"reactSnap": {
  "asyncScriptTags": true
}
```

This adds the **async** attribute to the main.js script tag of the generated pages. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! I am facing same issue with create-react-app scaffold tool, can you be more specific? So you install that package with npm and add this config to package.json and that's all?

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, that should be all.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem ejecting react-scripts and modifying the configuration files.

Basically you install this new webpack plugin: [Script Extension for HTML Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin).
And then you add this snippet to both dev and prod webpack configurations, within plugins array:

```
new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
    defaultAttribute: 'async'
})
```